# Get Child of Canvas

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, windows-store-apps, windows-store

I am manipulating `Canvas` delta, canvas has two children (`Rectangle` and `Thumb`). I want my manipulation delta to only work when I click on `Rectangle`. Is there a way I can get which `Canvas` child is clicked.

```
void rec_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var recSender = (Canvas)sender; // Get the Rectangle
    var rec=recSender.Children[1] as Rectangle;

    //if (e.OriginalSource is Rectangle)
    {            
        TranslateTransform ttSender = recSender.RenderTransform as TranslateTransform; // Get the Rectangle's RenderTransform (which is a TranslateTransform)

        ttSender.X += e.Delta.Translation.X;
        ttSender.Y += e.Delta.Translation.Y;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is wrong with `e.OriginalSource`?

Comment: OriginalSource return true only to canvas. @ArtemKulikov

Comment: I modified my answer to be more specific. Hopefully this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood your problem fully. I think you have to set the Property

```
 ManipulationMode="All"
```

of the child elements to be able to access them with e.OriginalSource. This will make the event bubble up the chain.

In my code it looks like this:

XAML

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <Canvas ManipulationMode="All"  ManipulationDelta="Canvas_ManipulationDelta" >
            <Rectangle ManipulationMode="All" Fill="Red" Width="100" Height="411"></Rectangle>
            <Ellipse ManipulationMode="All" Fill="Green" Width="400" Height="130"></Ellipse>
        </Canvas>
    </Grid>
```

CS:

```
 private void Canvas_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var x = e.OriginalSource;    
        }
```

Now when I klick the ellipse I get:
[image: Original Source breakpoint]

So I got access to the object. Works on my machine running Windows 10, VS2015.